# What is correct implementation of LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis)?

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, supervised-learning

I found that the result of LDA in OpenCV is different from other libraries. For example, the input data was

```
DATA (13 data samples with 4 dimensions)
  7    26     6    60
 1    29    15    52
11    56     8    20
11    31     8    47
 7    52     6    33
11    55     9    22
 3    71    17     6
 1    31    22    44
 2    54    18    22
21    47     4    26
 1    40    23    34
11    66     9    12
10    68     8    12

LABEL
 0     1     2     0     1     2     0     1     2     0     1     2     0
```

The OpenCV code is

```
Mat data = (Mat_<float>(13, 4) <<\
        7, 26, 6, 60,\
        1, 29, 15, 52,\
        11, 56, 8, 20,\
        11, 31, 8, 47,\
        7, 52, 6, 33,\
        11, 55, 9, 22,\
        3, 71, 17, 6,\
        1, 31, 22, 44,\
        2, 54, 18, 22,\
        21, 47, 4, 26,\
        1, 40, 23, 34,\
        11, 66, 9, 12,\
        10, 68, 8, 12);

Mat mean;
reduce(data, mean, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
mean.convertTo(mean, CV_64F);

Mat label(data.rows, 1, CV_32SC1);
for (int i=0; i<label.rows; i++)
    label.at<int>(i) = i%3;

LDA lda(data, label);
Mat projection = lda.subspaceProject(lda.eigenvectors(), mean, data);
```

The matlab code is (used [Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction](http://lvdmaaten.github.io/drtoolbox/))

```
cd drtoolbox\techniques\
load hald
label=[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
[projection, trainedlda] = lda(ingredients, label)
```

The eigenvalues are

```
OpenCV (lda.eigenvectors())
0.4457    4.0132
0.4880    3.5703
0.5448    3.3466
0.5162    3.5794

Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction (trainedlda.M)
0.5613    0.7159
0.6257    0.6203
0.6898    0.5884
0.6635    0.6262
```

Then the projections of data are

```
OpenCV
1.3261    7.1276
0.8892   -4.7569
-1.8092   -6.1947
-0.0720    1.1927
0.0768    3.3105
-0.7200    0.7405
-0.3788   -4.7388
1.5490   -2.8255
-0.3166   -8.8295
-0.8259    9.8953
1.3239   -3.1406
-0.5140    4.2194
-0.5285    4.0001

Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction
1.8030    1.3171
1.2128   -0.8311
-2.3390   -1.0790
-0.0686    0.3192
0.1583    0.5392
-0.9479    0.1414
-0.5238   -0.9722
1.9852   -0.4809
-0.4173   -1.6266
-1.1358    1.9009
1.6719   -0.5711
-0.6996    0.7034
-0.6993    0.6397
```

The eigenvectors and projections are different even though these LDAs have the same data. I believe there are 2 possibilities.

1. One of the libraries is wrong.
2. I am doing it wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: And how about the classes? How one could check the analyses you display?

Comment: What is the code you used? This isn't answerable in its present form.

Comment: How many classes are there? Can you give us the class labels? Are these matrices meant to be weight vectors for classification, or just vectors spanning the discriminative subspace?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the original data are 4 class centroids in a 13-dimensional space? What about within-class covariances?

Comment: I made the question more clear thanks to your advices. Thank you ttnphns, gung, A. Donda!

Comment: Hyunjun, thanks, the question is much clearer now. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer. I would have thought that the two algorithms just produce two different eigenvector bases for the same 2-dimensional subspace, but that doesn't seem to be the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is because eigenvectors are not normalized.
The normalized (L2 norm) eigenvectors are

```
OpenCV
0.44569   0.55196
0.48798   0.49105
0.54478   0.46028
0.51618   0.49230

Matlab Toolbox for Dimensionality Reduction
0.44064   0.55977
0.49120   0.48502
0.54152   0.46008
0.52087   0.48963
```

They look simliar now, although they have quite different eigenvalues.

Even though the PCA in OpenCV returns normalized eigenvectors, LDA does not. My next question is 'Is normalizing eigenvectors in LDA not necessary?'